# Comparing Data by time in Sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I have the data

```
SELECT [Dt]
      ,x1
      ,[SaleCount]
      ,x2
      ,x3
      ,action
  FROM table
```

action is an action( 0 no it, 1 is).
The essence of the matter is as follows:
for example for group

```
x1 + x2 + x3
1    2    2017
```

may be an action, and here there are some options for the influence of this group on the other.
such as a group

```
x1 + x2 + x3,
2 + 3 + 2017
```

I need to restructure the data, so that there are certain combinations.
`There is a action on the group 1 + 2 + 2017 and no action on the group 2 + 3 + 2017(no marker)`;

```
or there is a action of the group 1 + 2 + 2017, but in group 2 + 3 + 2017 was also action before the action for  group 1 + 2 + 2017(marker before)
```

(that is, the ones by action column for 2+3+2017 go before the ones by action column for  of group 1 + 2 + 2017)

```
or there is a action on the group 1 + 2 + 2017, but on the group 2 + 3 + 2017 there was also an action AFTER the action group 1 + 2 + 2017(marker after)
```

(that is, the ones by action column for 2+3+2017 go after the ones by action column for  of group 1 + 2 + 2017)

So I need to allocate combinations of action corresponding to these conditions.
data sample

```
Declare @t table 
(Dt date,
  x1 int,
  Sale int,
  x2 int,
  x3 int,
  action int,
  typegroup varchar);
insert into @t values
('23.07.2018',1,2,2017,1,0,basis),
('24.07.2018',1,2,2017,2,0,basis),
('25.07.2018',1,2,2017,3,0,basis),
('26.07.2018',1,2,2017,4,0,basis),
('27.07.2018',1,2,2017,5,0,basis),
('28.07.2018',1,2,2017,6,0,basis),
('29.07.2018',1,2,2017,7,0,basis),
('30.07.2018',1,2,2017,8,0,basis),
('31.07.2018',1,2,2017,9,0,basis),
('01.08.2018',1,2,2017,10,0,basis),
('02.08.2018',1,2,2017,11,0,basis),
('03.08.2018',1,2,2017,12,1,basis),
('04.08.2018',1,2,2017,13,1,basis),
('05.08.2018',1,2,2017,14,1,basis),
('06.08.2018',1,2,2017,15,1,basis),
('07.08.2018',1,2,2017,16,1,basis),
('08.08.2018',1,2,2017,17,1,basis),
('09.08.2018',1,2,2017,18,1,basis),
('10.08.2018',1,2,2017,19,1,basis),
('11.08.2018',1,2,2017,20,1,basis),
('12.08.2018',1,2,2017,21,1,basis),
('13.08.2018',1,2,2017,22,1,basis),
('14.08.2018',1,2,2017,23,1,basis),
('15.08.2018',1,2,2017,24,1,basis),
('16.08.2018',1,2,2017,25,1,basis),
('17.08.2018',1,2,2017,26,1,basis),
('18.08.2018',1,2,2017,27,0,basis),
('19.08.2018',1,2,2017,28,0,basis),
('20.08.2018',1,2,2017,29,0,basis),
('21.08.2018',1,2,2017,30,0,basis),
('22.08.2018',1,2,2017,31,0,basis),
('23.08.2018',1,2,2017,32,0,basis),
('24.08.2018',1,2,2017,33,0,basis),
('25.08.2018',1,2,2017,34,0,basis),
('23.07.2018',2,3,2017,1,0,no),
('24.07.2018',2,3,2017,2,0,no),
('25.07.2018',2,3,2017,3,0,no),
('26.07.2018',2,3,2017,4,0,no),
('27.07.2018',2,3,2017,5,0,no),
('28.07.2018',2,3,2017,6,0,no),
('29.07.2018',2,3,2017,7,0,no),
('30.07.2018',2,3,2017,8,0,no),
('31.07.2018',2,3,2017,9,0,no),
('01.08.2018',2,3,2017,10,0,no),
('02.08.2018',2,3,2017,11,0,no),
('03.08.2018',2,3,2017,12,0,no),
('04.08.2018',2,3,2017,13,0,no),
('05.08.2018',2,3,2017,14,0,no),
('06.08.2018',2,3,2017,15,0,no),
('07.08.2018',2,3,2017,16,0,no),
('08.08.2018',2,3,2017,17,0,no),
('09.08.2018',2,3,2017,18,0,no),
('10.08.2018',2,3,2017,19,0,no),
('11.08.2018',2,3,2017,20,0,no),
('12.08.2018',2,3,2017,21,0,no),
('13.08.2018',2,3,2017,22,0,no),
('14.08.2018',2,3,2017,23,0,no),
('15.08.2018',2,3,2017,24,0,no),
('16.08.2018',2,3,2017,25,0,no),
('17.08.2018',2,3,2017,26,0,no),
('18.08.2018',2,3,2017,27,0,no),
('19.08.2018',2,3,2017,28,0,no),
('20.08.2018',2,3,2017,29,0,no),
('21.08.2018',2,3,2017,30,0,no),
('22.08.2018',2,3,2017,31,0,no),
('23.08.2018',2,3,2017,32,0,no),
('24.08.2018',2,3,2017,33,0,no),
('25.08.2018',2,3,2017,34,0,no),
('23.07.2018',3,4,2017,1,1,before),
('24.07.2018',3,4,2017,2,1,before),
('25.07.2018',3,4,2017,3,1,before),
('26.07.2018',3,4,2017,4,1,before),
('27.07.2018',3,4,2017,5,1,before),
('28.07.2018',3,4,2017,6,1,before),
('29.07.2018',3,4,2017,7,1,before),
('30.07.2018',3,4,2017,8,1,before),
('31.07.2018',3,4,2017,9,1,before),
('01.08.2018',3,4,2017,10,1,before),
('02.08.2018',3,4,2017,11,0,before),
('03.08.2018',3,4,2017,12,0,before),
('04.08.2018',3,4,2017,13,0,before),
('05.08.2018',3,4,2017,14,0,before),
('06.08.2018',3,4,2017,15,0,before),
('07.08.2018',3,4,2017,16,0,before),
('08.08.2018',3,4,2017,17,0,before),
('09.08.2018',3,4,2017,18,0,before),
('10.08.2018',3,4,2017,19,0,before),
('11.08.2018',3,4,2017,20,0,before),
('12.08.2018',3,4,2017,21,0,before),
('13.08.2018',3,4,2017,22,0,before),
('14.08.2018',3,4,2017,23,0,before),
('15.08.2018',3,4,2017,24,0,before),
('16.08.2018',3,4,2017,25,0,before),
('17.08.2018',3,4,2017,26,0,before),
('18.08.2018',3,4,2017,27,0,before),
('19.08.2018',3,4,2017,28,0,before),
('20.08.2018',3,4,2017,29,0,before),
('21.08.2018',3,4,2017,30,0,before),
('22.08.2018',3,4,2017,31,0,before),
('23.08.2018',3,4,2017,32,0,before),
('24.08.2018',3,4,2017,33,0,before);
```

#

```
I compare by time, i.e. at the same time, i looking for all group that meet the above conditions.
In this example, for the group 1 + 2 + 2017
group 2 + 3 + 2017 did not have action
and the group 3 + 4 + 2017 had a action before starting action for 1 + 2 + 2017
and nothing more no.
NOW Let's work  the next group for example 3 + 4 + 2017, look at the time when it had an action and how it affected other group in th
```

e same time under the specified conditions. I.E 3 + 4 + 2017 became basis.

How to do it?

For group, markers must be generated.
the basis is the group  for which we are looking for comparisons.
and everything with which it is compared, marked
" no", or "before", or the flag of the "after" , depending on what combination of group in time sql found.

In other words, there can be very many such recombinations of striations with each other.

I.E. in relation to one group, 1 + 2 + 2017 may be the basis , and to the other, for example to 10 + 10 + 2017, it can not have any action at all.

Comment: sorry i am quite lost on the `strata` & `stratum`. I have problem understanding that.

Comment: @Squirrel, strata and stratum  mean group columns. For example x1 is shop, x2 is stuff, x3 is number . I.E. supermarket+coca_cola+123 it is group. Strata synonym for the group. Now did you inderstand what  i mean?

Comment: in the beginning you mention `x1 + x2 + x3   1 + 2 + 2017` but in the later part, the sample data for `x1, x2, x3` is `1 2017 1`

Comment: please also show what is your expected result

Comment: @Squirrel, where i mentioned 1 2017 1. Maybe it mistake. What i want i represented in data sample

Declare @t table ... for each basis group I have to find at the same time. a group that does not have action
, the group where action was before the action of the basis group, 
and the group where action was after the basis group's action. Maybe one condition is met or all at once. depends on the group. Do you inderstand me?

Comment: Also i edited post where, i  renamed  strata to group, to be more clearely.

Answer (score 0):

Here i found the good solution. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/d891c693-2d38-4064-9784-4b21cd2fca11/comparing-data-by-time-in-sql?forum=transactsql
It works.

```
set dateformat dmy
go

Declare @t table 
(Dt date,
  x1 int,
  x2 int,
  x3 int,
  sale int,
  action int,
  typegroup varchar(20));
insert into @t values
('23.07.2018',1,2,2017,1,0,''),
('24.07.2018',1,2,2017,2,0,''),
('25.07.2018',1,2,2017,3,0,''),
('26.07.2018',1,2,2017,4,0,''),
('27.07.2018',1,2,2017,5,0,''),
('28.07.2018',1,2,2017,6,0,''),
('29.07.2018',1,2,2017,7,0,''),
('30.07.2018',1,2,2017,8,0,''),
('31.07.2018',1,2,2017,9,0,''),
('01.08.2018',1,2,2017,10,0,''),
('02.08.2018',1,2,2017,11,0,''),
('03.08.2018',1,2,2017,12,1,''),
('04.08.2018',1,2,2017,13,1,''),
('05.08.2018',1,2,2017,14,1,''),
('06.08.2018',1,2,2017,15,1,''),
('07.08.2018',1,2,2017,16,1,''),
('08.08.2018',1,2,2017,17,1,''),
('09.08.2018',1,2,2017,18,1,''),
('10.08.2018',1,2,2017,19,1,''),
('11.08.2018',1,2,2017,20,1,''),
('12.08.2018',1,2,2017,21,1,''),
('13.08.2018',1,2,2017,22,1,''),
('14.08.2018',1,2,2017,23,1,''),
('15.08.2018',1,2,2017,24,1,''),
('16.08.2018',1,2,2017,25,1,''),
('17.08.2018',1,2,2017,26,1,''),
('18.08.2018',1,2,2017,27,0,''),
('19.08.2018',1,2,2017,28,0,''),
('20.08.2018',1,2,2017,29,0,''),
('21.08.2018',1,2,2017,30,0,''),
('22.08.2018',1,2,2017,31,0,''),
('23.08.2018',1,2,2017,32,0,''),
('24.08.2018',1,2,2017,33,0,''),
('25.08.2018',1,2,2017,34,0,''),
('23.07.2018',2,3,2017,1,0,''),
('24.07.2018',2,3,2017,2,0,''),
('25.07.2018',2,3,2017,3,0,''),
('26.07.2018',2,3,2017,4,0,''),
('27.07.2018',2,3,2017,5,0,''),
('28.07.2018',2,3,2017,6,0,''),
('29.07.2018',2,3,2017,7,0,''),
('30.07.2018',2,3,2017,8,0,''),
('31.07.2018',2,3,2017,9,0,''),
('01.08.2018',2,3,2017,10,0,''),
('02.08.2018',2,3,2017,11,0,''),
('03.08.2018',2,3,2017,12,0,''),
('04.08.2018',2,3,2017,13,0,''),
('05.08.2018',2,3,2017,14,0,''),
('06.08.2018',2,3,2017,15,0,''),
('07.08.2018',2,3,2017,16,0,''),
('08.08.2018',2,3,2017,17,0,''),
('09.08.2018',2,3,2017,18,0,''),
('10.08.2018',2,3,2017,19,0,''),
('11.08.2018',2,3,2017,20,0,''),
('12.08.2018',2,3,2017,21,0,''),
('13.08.2018',2,3,2017,22,0,''),
('14.08.2018',2,3,2017,23,0,''),
('15.08.2018',2,3,2017,24,0,''),
('16.08.2018',2,3,2017,25,0,''),
('17.08.2018',2,3,2017,26,0,''),
('18.08.2018',2,3,2017,27,0,''),
('19.08.2018',2,3,2017,28,0,''),
('20.08.2018',2,3,2017,29,0,''),
('21.08.2018',2,3,2017,30,0,''),
('22.08.2018',2,3,2017,31,0,''),
('23.08.2018',2,3,2017,32,0,''),
('24.08.2018',2,3,2017,33,0,''),
('25.08.2018',2,3,2017,34,0,''),
('23.07.2018',3,4,2017,1,1,''),
('24.07.2018',3,4,2017,2,1,''),
('25.07.2018',3,4,2017,3,1,''),
('26.07.2018',3,4,2017,4,1,''),
('27.07.2018',3,4,2017,5,1,''),
('28.07.2018',3,4,2017,6,1,''),
('29.07.2018',3,4,2017,7,1,''),
('30.07.2018',3,4,2017,8,1,''),
('31.07.2018',3,4,2017,9,1,''),
('01.08.2018',3,4,2017,10,1,''),
('02.08.2018',3,4,2017,11,0,''),
('03.08.2018',3,4,2017,12,0,''),
('04.08.2018',3,4,2017,13,0,''),
('05.08.2018',3,4,2017,14,0,''),
('06.08.2018',3,4,2017,15,0,''),
('07.08.2018',3,4,2017,16,0,''),
('08.08.2018',3,4,2017,17,0,''),
('09.08.2018',3,4,2017,18,0,''),
('10.08.2018',3,4,2017,19,0,''),
('11.08.2018',3,4,2017,20,0,''),
('12.08.2018',3,4,2017,21,0,''),
('13.08.2018',3,4,2017,22,0,''),
('14.08.2018',3,4,2017,23,0,''),
('15.08.2018',3,4,2017,24,0,''),
('16.08.2018',3,4,2017,25,0,''),
('17.08.2018',3,4,2017,26,0,''),
('18.08.2018',3,4,2017,27,1,''),
('19.08.2018',3,4,2017,28,1,''),
('20.08.2018',3,4,2017,29,1,''),
('21.08.2018',3,4,2017,30,1,''),
('22.08.2018',3,4,2017,31,1,''),
('23.08.2018',3,4,2017,32,1,''),
('24.08.2018',3,4,2017,33,1,'');

declare @x1 int,
  @x2 int,
  @x3 int,@mindt date,@maxdt date

--pass any group values here
  select @x1 = 1, @x2 = 2,@x3= 2017


  Select @mindt = min(Dt), @maxdt = max(Dt)
from @t
where x1 = @x1
and  x2 = @x2
and x3 = @x3
and action =1

  update r
  set typegroup= type
  from (select *,
  case              when x1=@x1 and x2 = @x2 and x3 = @x3 then 'basis'
                when  action = 1 and max(Dt) over (partition by nxt) > coalesce(@maxdt,'99991231') then 'after'
                when  action = 1 and min(Dt) over (partition by nxt) < coalesce(@mindt,'19000101') then 'before'

                end as type
                from @t t
                outer apply
  (
Select min(Dt) as nxt
from @t
where x1 = t.x1
and  x2 = t.x2
and x3 = t.x3
and action <> t.action
and Dt > t.Dt
)t1)r


select *
from @t
order by x1,x2,x3,sale

/*
Output
-----------------------------------------------------------
Dt  x1  x2  x3  sale    action  typegroup
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
2018-07-23  1   2   2017    1   0   basis
2018-07-24  1   2   2017    2   0   basis
2018-07-25  1   2   2017    3   0   basis
2018-07-26  1   2   2017    4   0   basis
2018-07-27  1   2   2017    5   0   basis
2018-07-28  1   2   2017    6   0   basis
2018-07-29  1   2   2017    7   0   basis
2018-07-30  1   2   2017    8   0   basis
2018-07-31  1   2   2017    9   0   basis
2018-08-01  1   2   2017    10  0   basis
2018-08-02  1   2   2017    11  0   basis
2018-08-03  1   2   2017    12  1   basis
2018-08-04  1   2   2017    13  1   basis
2018-08-05  1   2   2017    14  1   basis
2018-08-06  1   2   2017    15  1   basis
2018-08-07  1   2   2017    16  1   basis
2018-08-08  1   2   2017    17  1   basis
2018-08-09  1   2   2017    18  1   basis
2018-08-10  1   2   2017    19  1   basis
2018-08-11  1   2   2017    20  1   basis
2018-08-12  1   2   2017    21  1   basis
2018-08-13  1   2   2017    22  1   basis
2018-08-14  1   2   2017    23  1   basis
2018-08-15  1   2   2017    24  1   basis
2018-08-16  1   2   2017    25  1   basis
2018-08-17  1   2   2017    26  1   basis
2018-08-18  1   2   2017    27  0   basis
2018-08-19  1   2   2017    28  0   basis
2018-08-20  1   2   2017    29  0   basis
2018-08-21  1   2   2017    30  0   basis
2018-08-22  1   2   2017    31  0   basis
2018-08-23  1   2   2017    32  0   basis
2018-08-24  1   2   2017    33  0   basis
2018-08-25  1   2   2017    34  0   basis
2018-07-23  2   3   2017    1   0   NULL
2018-07-24  2   3   2017    2   0   NULL
2018-07-25  2   3   2017    3   0   NULL
2018-07-26  2   3   2017    4   0   NULL
2018-07-27  2   3   2017    5   0   NULL
2018-07-28  2   3   2017    6   0   NULL
2018-07-29  2   3   2017    7   0   NULL
2018-07-30  2   3   2017    8   0   NULL
2018-07-31  2   3   2017    9   0   NULL
2018-08-01  2   3   2017    10  0   NULL
2018-08-02  2   3   2017    11  0   NULL
2018-08-03  2   3   2017    12  0   NULL
2018-08-04  2   3   2017    13  0   NULL
2018-08-05  2   3   2017    14  0   NULL
2018-08-06  2   3   2017    15  0   NULL
2018-08-07  2   3   2017    16  0   NULL
2018-08-08  2   3   2017    17  0   NULL
2018-08-09  2   3   2017    18  0   NULL
2018-08-10  2   3   2017    19  0   NULL
2018-08-11  2   3   2017    20  0   NULL
2018-08-12  2   3   2017    21  0   NULL
2018-08-13  2   3   2017    22  0   NULL
2018-08-14  2   3   2017    23  0   NULL
2018-08-15  2   3   2017    24  0   NULL
2018-08-16  2   3   2017    25  0   NULL
2018-08-17  2   3   2017    26  0   NULL
2018-08-18  2   3   2017    27  0   NULL
2018-08-19  2   3   2017    28  0   NULL
2018-08-20  2   3   2017    29  0   NULL
2018-08-21  2   3   2017    30  0   NULL
2018-08-22  2   3   2017    31  0   NULL
2018-08-23  2   3   2017    32  0   NULL
2018-08-24  2   3   2017    33  0   NULL
2018-08-25  2   3   2017    34  0   NULL
2018-07-23  3   4   2017    1   1   before
2018-07-24  3   4   2017    2   1   before
2018-07-25  3   4   2017    3   1   before
2018-07-26  3   4   2017    4   1   before
2018-07-27  3   4   2017    5   1   before
2018-07-28  3   4   2017    6   1   before
2018-07-29  3   4   2017    7   1   before
2018-07-30  3   4   2017    8   1   before
2018-07-31  3   4   2017    9   1   before
2018-08-01  3   4   2017    10  1   before
2018-08-02  3   4   2017    11  0   NULL
2018-08-03  3   4   2017    12  0   NULL
2018-08-04  3   4   2017    13  0   NULL
2018-08-05  3   4   2017    14  0   NULL
2018-08-06  3   4   2017    15  0   NULL
2018-08-07  3   4   2017    16  0   NULL
2018-08-08  3   4   2017    17  0   NULL
2018-08-09  3   4   2017    18  0   NULL
2018-08-10  3   4   2017    19  0   NULL
2018-08-11  3   4   2017    20  0   NULL
2018-08-12  3   4   2017    21  0   NULL
2018-08-13  3   4   2017    22  0   NULL
2018-08-14  3   4   2017    23  0   NULL
2018-08-15  3   4   2017    24  0   NULL
2018-08-16  3   4   2017    25  0   NULL
2018-08-17  3   4   2017    26  0   NULL
2018-08-18  3   4   2017    27  1   after
2018-08-19  3   4   2017    28  1   after
2018-08-20  3   4   2017    29  1   after
2018-08-21  3   4   2017    30  1   after
2018-08-22  3   4   2017    31  1   after
2018-08-23  3   4   2017    32  1   after
2018-08-24  3   4   2017    33  1   after
```